# Load Files into React component

Tags: reactjs, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file in a React component through this:

```
<div className="addDocumentField">
   <label htmlFor="file-input" />
   <input id="file-input" type="file" name="myImage" onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
</div>
```

In handleInputChange, we have:

```
 public handleInputChange(event: any) {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;

      if(name === 'myImage'){
        this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
      }else{
        this.setState({
          [name]: value,
        });
      }
  }
```

But the value obtained in event.target.files[0] always comes to '{}'.
Does anyone know how to load the document into the variable correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload a folder you need to add these two properties to your `input`

```
webkitdirectory="true" mozdirectory="true"
```